# Xcode 10: Failed to create Provisioning Profile - There are no devices registered

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

When I try to create a profile to build an iOS app by going to Project → General → Signing, and selecting my Team (Personal), I get two errors:

> Failed to create provisioning profile.
>
> There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

And:

> No profiles for 'com.my.app.id' were found
>
> Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profile matching 'com.my.app.id'.

---

I tried to check many tutorials and questions but nothing helped me to solve these errors. Many URLs take me to the Apple Development website, but there I only have the option to pay for the membership, and as I understood that's not necessary to build and run an app on an iOS device.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Have you connected your device to your Mac? Have you selected in as the run destination?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and both thanks for your comment. Apparently yes the problem was that I didn't select my device as run destination. If you answer it I would be glad to give you the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have connected your iOS device to your Mac and selected it as the run destination.

Yes, you do not need a paid membership to the Apple developer program. You can register for an Apple developer account for free and can build and run apps on a maximum of upto three devices.

Comment: I am receiving exact same problems, and I search a lot to find a solution. My case is different with other. I don't have a Mac device, I subscribed a MacOS from a cloud services (MacinCloud). Therefore, I can't plug in my iPhone to the server which the MacOS is there. Can you please help me with that? Is there any solution for my case or I have to have a Mac device to link my app to my iPhone for debugging. Thank you so much

Comment: Can it just be an ios emulator?

Comment: @Shittel You can try adding your device in the Apple Developer Provisioning Portal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15804489/6995250

Comment: @ShivamSahil No.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Do I need a newish iOS device to be able to uploaded to the apple store?  It doesn't seem like there's a way around this error without one.

Comment: @KevinWatt You do not need a newish iOS device. But make sure to use a recent enough or better the latest version of macOS and Xcode.